# lock zend studio to launcher/dash gnome shell

Tags: gnome, zend

I am using Zend Studio in Gnome Shell and I can launch Zend Studio from the folder binary file, but I don't get the option to lock it to the dash as a favorite.

Any idea on how I can go about doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link is for unity but it works for gnome 3 as well.

http://saji89.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/how-to-add-an-entry-for-zend-studio-in-your-ubuntu-programs-list/

I created "/usr/share/applications/zendstudio.desktop" with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=10
Name=Zend Studio
GenericName=PHP IDE
X-GNOME-FullName=Zend Studio PHP IDE
Comment=PHP IDE
Exec=/usr/local/lib/ZendStudio/ZendStudio
Icon=/usr/local/lib/ZendStudio/icon.xpm
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;IDE;CODE;PHP
```

The ZendStudio directory is under my /usr/local/lib/. In Gnome 3 I can search for the application.